# How do I append values to make a multi-dimentional list?

Tags: python, list

My code:

```
list=[["Uno","Dos"],[1,2],["Tres","Cuatro"],[3,4]]

print(list)

list[4][0].insert(A)

New_list=[[],[],[],[]]

A=list[0][0]+str(list[1][0])
B=(list[0][0]+str(list[1][0]))[::-1]
C=list[0][1]+str(list[1][1])
D=(list[0][1]+str(list[1][1]))[::-1]
E=list[2][0]+str(list[3][0])
F=(list[2][0]+str(list[3][0]))[::-1]
G=list[2][1]+str(list[3][1])
H=(list[2][1]+str(list[3][1]))[::-1]

New_list[0][0].append(A)

print(New_list)
```

My expectation:

```
[["Uno1","1onU"],["Dos2","2soD"],["Tres3","3serT"],["Cuatro4","4ortauC"]]
```

I've tried to use append and insert but every time I get an error message; usually "list index is out of range"

How can I add my values to New_list?

Comment: you should not be making lists like that.

Comment: You need to *actually read the error message* - your code is dying on the third line you show (`list[4]` is invalid for a list with only four elements - their indexes are 0 thru 3).  Nothing after that point is relevant.

Comment: I recommend learning about list comprehensions. With this tool, you don't have to call `append()` very often.

Comment: don't use `list` as a variable name, it's the name of a built-in type constructor.

Comment: You're doing `list[4][0].insert(A)` before you assign `A`. And there is no `list[4]`, the indexes go from 0 to 3. What are you expecting that to do?

Answer (score 0):

`append` appends a value to your list inline. `list[4][0]` gives an error, because that value does not exist yet. With `insert` you can add entries to your list and specify the location as well where you want the entry to be insert, whereas `append` always attaches to the end of the list.

Example:

```
l = []
l.append("a")
print(l)
# ['a']
l.append(["b", "c"])
print(l)
# ['a', ['b', 'c']]
l.insert(0, "d")
print(l)
# ['d', 'a', ['b', 'c']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question *"How do I append values to make a multi-dimentional list?"* You can append a list to a list, making it multi-dimensional. Small example:

```py
my_list = []

my_list.append([1, 2, 3])
my_list.append([4, 5, 6])
my_list.append([7, 8, 9])

print(my_list)
# prints my_list (formatted nicely):
# [
#   [1,2,3],
#   [4,5,6],
#   [7,8,9]
# ]
```

You are also trying to access out of bounds of your list on line 3, causing an error. Remember index starts at 0 for lists.

Answer (score 0):

Use loops to perform similar operations through the list, rather than assigning separate variables for each list element.

```
old_list = [["Uno","Dos"],[1,2],["Tres","Cuatro"],[3,4]]
new_list = []

for i in range(0, len(old_list), 2):
    num_strings = old_list[i]
    nums = old_list[i+1]
    for s, num in zip(num_strings, nums):
        new_list.append([f'{s}{num}', f'{num}{s[::-1]}'])

print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

got something for you :

```
list=[["Uno","Dos"],[1,2],["Tres","Cuatro"],[3,4]]

A = list[0][0]+str(list[1][0])
reverse_A = A[::-1]
elemA = [A, reverse_A]

B = list[0][1]+str(list[1][1])
reverse_B = B[::-1]
elemB = [B, reverse_B]

C = list[2][0]+str(list[3][0])
reverse_C = C[::-1]
elemC = [C, reverse_C]

D = list[2][1]+str(list[3][1])
reverse_D = D[::-1]
elemD = [D, reverse_D]

new_list = [elemA, elemB, elemC, elemD]

print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you cannot use list as an alias. Secondly, lists start numbering at 0, none of your lists have an element at list[4]. That would be a fifth element. Try this.

```
lista = [['Uno','Dos'],[1,2],['Tres','Cuatro'],[3,4]]

A = lista[0][0]+str(lista[1][0])
B = lista[0][1]+str(lista[1][1])
C = lista[2][0]+str(lista[3][0])
D = lista[2][1]+str(lista[3][1])

Lists = A, B, C, D

New_List = []

for lisx in Lists:
     New_List.append((lisx, lisx[::-1]))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think trying to do it by hand is little bit harder as when list grows.
U can wrap it inside a **FOR** loop as below:

```
for i in range(0,len(list),2):
  str1=list[i][0]+str(list[i+1][0])
  str2=list[i][1]+str(list[i+1][1])
  New_list.append([str1,str1[::-1]])
  New_list.append([str2,str2[::-1]])
```

This one can adapt to bigger lists automatically. I hope I've given you u the answer you were looking for